# MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found with php

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp, php-mongodb

I am having problems with mongo in php, I am working with wamp

I have already put extension=php_mongodb.dll in php.ini

It is working when I call the script in the browser
[image: browser]

But when I call the script in console it show this error
[image: error in console]

Need help

Comment: Console and Web are two different PHP. Put the `extension=php_mongodb.dll` also in the so called `php-cli` version php.ini.

Comment: @DanielW. thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Console" and "Web" are using two different PHP binaries (and configurations).

Put the `extension=php_mongodb.dll` also in the so called `php-cli` version `php.ini` and the problem should be solved.